# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input tinymce.min.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I wanted to add new post to my WordPress website and I saw that buttons are missing and the text in the textarea is white. I've tried to do everything described [here](https://mythemeshop.com/blog/fix-white-text-and-missing-buttons-error/), but it didn't help.

Then I opened console in my browsers (Chrome and Firefox also) and I saw the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input tinymce.min.js:2

In "Application" tab I opened this file and it ends like this:

> "TABLE"===n.nodeName?r=""+a+"":/^(UL|OL)$/.t

But on the server this file is full, it is not corrupted. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced wp-includes with the original one and it helped.